# ListView not displaying proper Sections while using SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

**EDITED**

I am working on a contact list and trying to implement sectioned listview. When the app gets started, only one of the Header (Section) starts displaying itself after some chunks of items repeatedly and changing its position on scrolling up/down.

Here is my code :

```
    private class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

         Holder holder = null;
         LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
//       String keyWord = "empty";

        public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cur,
                String[] from, int[] to, int flag) {
            super(context, layout, cur, from, to, flag);
        }

        public String getTitle(String contName) {
            return contName.substring(0, 1);
         }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor mCursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            holder = new Holder();
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            String cont_Name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            View view = null;

                    if ( ! keyWord.equalsIgnoreCase(getTitle(cont_Name))  || keyWord.equals(null))
                    {
                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.section_header, null);
                        TextView sectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title2);
                        sectionTitle.setText(getTitle(cont_Name));
                        keyWord = getTitle(cont_Name);
                        Log.d("KeyWord", keyWord);
                        Log.d("Contact Name", cont_Name);

                    }
                    else if(keyWord.equalsIgnoreCase(getTitle(cont_Name))) {

                        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pm_fragment, null);

                        holder.contactTitle= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                        holder.contactDetail = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                        holder.contactTitle.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                        holder.contactDetail.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));

                        Log.d("KeyWord", keyWord);
                        Log.d("Contact Name", cont_Name);

                        String contactId_String = ""+mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID));
                        long contactId = Long.parseLong(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID)));

                        DatabaseHandler handler = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
                        Contact matchedContact = handler.getContact(contactId) ;
                        String dbContactId= "";
                        if(matchedContact != null){

                            if(matchedContact.getID() != 0 && ""+matchedContact.getID() != null){
                                dbContactId= ""+matchedContact.getID();
                            }

                            if(dbContactId.equals(contactId_String)){
                                holder.myImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);          
                                holder.myImage.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                                holder.myImage.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
                                holder.myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.person_empty_online);
                            }
                        }else{
                            holder.myImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);          
                            holder.myImage.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
                            holder.myImage.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
                            holder.myImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.person_empty_offline);
                        }
                        handler.close();
                        keyWord = getTitle(cont_Name);
                    }
            return view;
        }

    }
```

During Debugging, After the ending line `return view ;` , it enters in `CursorAdapter.class` and passes by through the lines:

```
if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
  throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
}
```

and enters in `if condtion`, but app doesn't crash.

Comment: On Scrolling down till the end of the list, and going back to upward, some of other sections also appear but not at prescribed positions, say randomly.

Comment: Its my 3rd question in a row, and no one is helping me, rather grading down this question...GREAT STACKOVERFLOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Got my answer my own after two weeks...my `if-else` conditions were too complex , so i make comparison on some different criteria.

```
if (mCursor.getPosition() > 0 && mCursor.moveToPrevious()) 
            {
                preName = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                mCursor.moveToNext();
            }
            else if(mCursor.getPosition() == 0)
            {
                preName = null;
            }
            else{
                preName = null;
            }

            if(preName != null){
                preTitle = getTitle(preName);
            }

//===============================================================================
            /*          
             * Setting Header And Contact Details
             */
//===============================================================================

            if(mCursor.isFirst()){
                holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.titleText.setText(itemTitle);
            }

            else if(preName != null){

                if(! itemTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(preTitle))
                {
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.titleText.setText(itemTitle);
                }else{
                    holder.titleText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            holder.contactTitle.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            holder.contactDetail.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
```